# How can I enable the 'tags' property to file types that don't have it normally?

Tags: windows-7

**Background:**
Here's the situation: I have a game that I'm adding mods to. Mods generally add extra files to the game folder. So I'd like a way of easily distinguishing between 'mod' and 'vanilla' files.

That's when I stumbled upon the 'Tags' feature in file properties. Simple! If I could just add tags to the files, I could sort by the 'Tags' column (once added to Explorer's columns of course).

Most guides online say it's as [simple as this](http://www.maketecheasier.com/add-tags-in-windows-files-for-quick-and-easy-searching/):

[image: Adding 'baby' tag to the file properties of an image file]

However, I'm finding that it's not as simple as that:

[image: File Properties Window of a .dll file. No tags to be seen anywhere]

**Question:**
Is it possible to enable the ability to add tags to different file types? Failing that, is there a third-party solution available?

Comment: This isn't in any way related to the question asked, but if you're looking for a way to quickly find files on your computer (much faster than Windows search) may I suggest using [Locate32](http://locate32.cogit.net/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows Explorer you can see quite a lot of document properties for many file types.  The nice, unified interface suggests that there is some unified property store. That's not really the case.

The Explorer Shell has an extensible interface for [Property Sheet Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144106(v=vs.85).aspx) that extract this information from various file types. There is a separate handler for every file-type, for example for [JFIF (JPEG) files](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/), and there are handlers for OLE files (old Office formats), and the new Office formats too.

In other words, there is no way to add the tags property across all file-types,
so a third-party utility is required.

There are many such products, and here is a list of some of them :

[Tabbles](http://tabbles.net/)
[TagsForAll](http://www.akslab.com/tagsforall/)
[Elyse](http://silkwoodsoftware.com/)
[tag2find](http://www.tag2find.com/)
[TagSpaces](http://www.tagspaces.org/)

(I have no experience with these products.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm an experienced modder, created some of the best mods out there. Please tell me what you are modding, what file types and extensions you are using, maybe I can find a simpler solution to your problem.

There are 3rd party solutions like [this one](http://www.tagspaces.org)

But I've always preferred to organize my own files.

**The file manager way**: use any decent file manager, set all original file attributes to archive (or read-only) and let your new files with no archive/ read only attribute. Then you can simply filter them by this criteria, even by using colors. Any decent FM should support sorting by file attributes.